# Disconnect http.createServer method in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I have a piece of code that uses the server with nodejs, in which there is a method that requires ports running programs then manually disconnected and reconnected to the same port.

but my trouble and not getting what method I use. 
sample code snippet:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(r, p){

   // Some Code

});
server.listen( 9999 );
server.on('error', function(e){ /*  */ });
```

I want to use the same port 9999.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the server stop listening on port 9999 you need to call the `server.close` method.

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback

Comment: Good answer, but whether it can be implemented in the 'http', because I see that the module 'net'

Answer (score 0):

http://www.nodebeginner.org/#hello-world

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();

}).listen(9999);
```

Comment: That's not the intent of my question but thanks for answering.